# Using update with Join and case

Tags: sql-server

I have 2 tables `employee` and `transport`

employee table:

```
name  organization vehicle
rajiv a            hyundai 
max   b            suzuki
```

transport table:

```
organization vehicle 
a            hyundai
b            suzuki
```

I want to add a column in employee table such that if a value exists in the vehicle column of transport table then value should be 1 else 0 of new column havingvehicle. Both tables can only be joined on basis of organization and vehicle.

Please suggest how can I accomplish these in update statement

```
alter table employee
ADD HAVINGVEHICLE VARCHAR(255)
```

Comment: If `HAVINGVEHICLE` can only be 1 or 0 why not use a `bit` datatype instead of `varchar`? Using the correct datatype is a very important aspect of good database design.

Comment: @DaleK yes it can be, will do it , thanks for your valuable advice

Answer (score 2):

You may use a `CASE` expression here with `EXISTS` logic:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT
        e.name,
        e.organization,
        e.vehicle,
        CASE WHEN EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM transport t
                          WHERE t.organization = e.organization AND t.vehicle = e.vehicle)
             THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS having_vehicle_new
    FROM employee e
)

UPDATE cte
SET having_vehicle = having_vehicle_new;
```

We could also a join/aggregation approach (query only shown):

```
SELECT
    e.name,
    e.organization,
    e.vehicle,
    CASE WHEN COUNT(t.organization) > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS having_vehicle
FROM employee e
LEFT JOIN transport t
    ON t.organization = e.organization AND t.vehicle = e.vehicle
GROUP BY
    e.name,
    e.organization,
    e.vehicle;
```

Given that this new column is really just derived data, I advocate actually *not* creating a new column.  Instead, just use one of the two select queries above, or maybe create a view.

Comment: Good answer @TimBiegeleisen, upvote from me. However, I do think you're missing the update statement which Rajiv asks for... _"Please suggest how can I accomplish these in update statement"_ ? :-)

Comment: @Birel I guess I missed that.  Actually, the OP might want to _not_ even add this column, since it just consists of derived data.  I left the second option as a query, in favor of this.

Comment: No problem! Good answer like I said

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen , getting error. Error is : Incorrect syntax near ')'. ( last line)

Comment: I have no idea of your table structure.  My first update assumes your new column is called `having_vehicle`.  If it isn't called that, you'll get an error.

Comment: Maybe you could make your absolutely correct advice stand out a bit more.